# How can I get the name of the current Quarto file?

Tags: r, quarto

I would like to add the name of the currently executing Quarto file to a report without hard coding it.  I am working with R inside of the RStudio IDE.   Both `` `r scriptName::current_filename()` ``and `` `r commandArgs()` `` return `/Applications/quarto/share/rmd/rmd.R`.  Is there a way to get the name of the Quarto script rather than the R file that is being processed by knitr?

Comment: This isn't exactly a duplicate as the answer is, it's not straightforward, but have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73588271/customizing-r-quarto-pdf-output-file-name)? A good suggestion of workarounds.

Comment: Thanks Sam.  I hadn't seen that one.  Unfortunately it looks like that version requires me to hard code the file name.  I am trying to enforce a reproducible workflow with novices.  So an automatic lookup is *highly* preferred over hoping the programmer didn't change the file name since they named it in code.

Comment: Fair enough. How exactly are you compiling it (I use vscode for Quarto - does RStudio have a button or are you entering a `quarto render` type command)? Have you tried `rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()` and `rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()`?

Comment: Great ideas but no luck.  I am working in the RStudio IDE.  This works if I run it from the console `rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()[2]` but not when I embed it in the script and try to render the the document (with the render button). I get `Error: RStudio not running`.  I think it is the same core problem were Quarto is starting a new process to make the document.  So the name is lost.

Comment: This would be easier if I tried it myself but for some reason RStudio always crashes when opened on my main PC! Is the behaviour the same when you try to render with `as_job = FALSE` (or globally set `options("quarto.render_as_job" = FALSE)`?

Comment: I tried it and I get the same issue with the API saying RStudio is not running.

Answer (score 1):

As a simpler workaround, you can pass the file name as a [parameter](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/parameters.html#knitr) to the document either using the [`quarto::quarto_render()`](https://quarto-dev.github.io/quarto-r/reference/quarto_render.html) or from [bash terminal](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/parameters.html#rendering).

Let's suppose the filename is *quarto_doc.qmd*

**quarto_doc.qmd**

```
---
title: "Quarto File Name"
format: html
params:
  filename: ""
---

## Quarto

you are running the file `r params$filename`
```

Then from bash terminal,

```
fname=quarto_doc.qmd
quarto render $fname -P filename:$fname
```

---

[image: current filename in the rendered output]

---

Or if you prefer using R function, you can create a wrapper function around `quarto::quarto_render` for convenience like this,

```
render_qmd <- function(input, ...) {
  input_file_name <- basename(input)
  quarto::quarto_render(input, execute_params = list(filename = input_file_name), ...)
}

render_qmd("quarto_doc.qmd")
```

Comment: This is helpful but I am hoping that there is a way to actually lookup the file name.  Given that nobody has come up with a solution I am thinking I need to put in a feature request on GitHub.