# How to dynamically set html filename when rendering Quarto documents in R

Tags: html, r, automation, filenames, quarto

I have a parameterized Quarto document, and want to automate the rendering and use some of those parameters in the YAML together with `Sys.Date()` to name the resulting html file, so that everytime i render the quarto document, the output html file does not overwrite the previous one.

I have tried the solution that works for RMarkdown shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71173343/dynamically-naming-the-output-file-in-a-custom-r-markdown-function/71174669#71174669) without success in Quarto because the key `Knit` does not seem to exist when used in the YAML in Quarto, so the html is made with the same name as the .qmd file. Here is a minimal example of what I tried based on the link i mentioned above

```
---
title: "Example"
author: "Anthony"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
params:
   variable: "var1"
knit: >
  (function(input_file, encoding) {
    metadata <- rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter(input_file)
    output_file <- with(metadata, paste0(title,"_",params$variable, "_", author, "_",date))
    rmarkdown::render(input = input_file, output_file = output_file)
---
```

I also tried the keys `output-file` and `output-ext` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73588271/customizing-r-quarto-pdf-output-file-name) for quarto documents, but it can only be used with strings without code looks like, so the YAML below does not work either.

```
---
params:
   variable = "variable1"
format:
   html: 
    output-file: "`r paste0("file_name","_",params$variable)`"
    output-ext:  "html"
title: "Testing Output filename"
---
```

Trying `output-file: "File {{< meta params.variable>}}"` in the last YAML did not work either (although this approach does work when used in the `title:` key).

So, I would like to automate generation of the html filename by adding the relevant code in the YAML, if possible. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Maybe this points you in some direction: https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/variables.html#meta

Comment: @Julian, thanks, I also tried that, and did not work unfortunately. I will update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a janky way of doing what you are after, but why don't you create a template qmd file with variable placeholders. Since it is just a plain text document, you can read it in using R, then replace the placeholders with text you need (date etc.) and then generate a new qmd file with the correct file name and date. This file can be rendered using `quarto::quarto_render("document.qmd")`. Something along these lines:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(quarto)

# you need to change the path to your template file
quarto_code_template <- read_file(r"{C:\Users\novot\Desktop\template.txt}")

output_file_name <- Sys.Date() %>%
  as.character() %>%
  paste0(".qmd")

# replacing the date placeholder with the actual date
quarto_code_actual <- quarto_code_template %>%
  str_replace("::date_placeholder::", as.character(Sys.Date()) )

# generating the quarto code file
write_file(quarto_code_actual, output_file_name)

# rendering an html document from the quarto file
quarto::quarto_render(output_file_name)
```

Template file code here:

```
---
title: "Example"
author: "Anthony"
date: "::date_placeholder::"
output: html_document
---
```

Comment: thanks, not sure I follow, could you make a minimal example?

Comment: @ForEverNewbie edited my answer to give you a minimal example how to incorporate date into the output html file and in the markdown text.

Comment: This does the work, thank you! It does generate a new .qmd every time I render the document as well, but that is a minor inconvenience.

Comment: @ForEverNewbie you can always delete the file using `file.remove` function from R.

Comment: Oh that is true, thanks again! Sorry my answers do not mention you, somehow the "@username" part is removed when the comment is added to the thread.